# Delete entities don`t work in Orion

Tags: fiware-orion

How can I delete entities? As I show in this code, the entity exist but I obtain error when I try to delete it.

```
[root@host-192-168-192-78 ~]# curl localhost:1026/v1/contextEntityTypes/Room -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/xml' | xmllint --format -
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<queryContextResponse>
  <contextResponseList>
    <contextElementResponse>
      <contextElement>
        <entityId type="Room" isPattern="false">
      <id>Bedroom1</id>
    </entityId>
    <contextAttributeList>
      <contextAttribute>
        <name>Temperature</name>
        <type>float</type>
        <contextValue>27.8</contextValue>
      </contextAttribute>
      <contextAttribute>
        <name>Presence</name>
        <type>boolean</type>
        <contextValue>true</contextValue>
      </contextAttribute>
      <contextAttribute>
        <name>Status</name>
        <type>string</type>
        <contextValue>OK</contextValue>
      </contextAttribute>
    </contextAttributeList>
  </contextElement>
  <statusCode>
    <code>200</code>
    <reasonPhrase>OK</reasonPhrase>
  </statusCode>
</contextElementResponse>
```

Above I check that entity exists, but now, when I try delete it I obtain the following:

```
[root@host-192-168-192-78 ~]# curl localhost:1026/NGSI10/contextEntities/Bedroom1 -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/xml' -X DELETE
<statusCode>
  <code>404</code>
  <reasonPhrase>No context element found</reasonPhrase>
  <details>Bedroom1</details>
</statusCode>
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include which contextBroker version are you using, please? I.e. `contextBroker --version`

Comment: [root@host-192-168-192-78 ~]# contextBroker --version
0.20.0

Comment: Could you try using the following URL: "localhost:1026/NGSI10/contextEntities/type/Room/id/Bedroom1", please?

Comment: I get error also...

[root@host-192-168-192-78 ~]# curl localhost:1026/NGSI10/contextEntities/type/Room/id/Bedroom1 -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/xml' -X DELETE
<orionError>
  <code>400</code>
  <reasonPhrase>Bad Request</reasonPhrase>
  <details>service not found</details>
</orionError>

Answer (score 1):

I think the URL used for DELETE is incorrect. It should be

localhost:1026/v1/contextEntities/Bedroom1

Comment: Both '/v1/' and '/NGSI10' are supported. If the URL is not recognized, the error response would be different.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug in the broker. The entity should be found and deleted.
We will look into this asap, please follow its evolution in orion github, [issue #921](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/921)

Comment: I made a quick functest to try to provoke this failure but it worked just fine.
So, what version of the broker are you using?

    contextBroker --version

Comment: [root@host-192-168-192-78 ~]# contextBroker --version 0.20.0

Comment: 0.20.0 is a very new version. What you want to do should work. Please follow the link to Issue 921 on our github and compare your message to the message I used in the test, when I tried to reproduce the error.